# I keep getting an attribute error is this

Tags: python, class, attributes

Create a class called Point.

The point should have two attributes:

```
Attribute Name      Description
x             x-coordinate of the point
y             y-cordinate of the point
```

You should override the **init**(), **str**(), **add**(), **sub**() and **mul**() methods
but my add sub and mul methods keep getting an attribute error
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'x'
how do i correct this error?

```
class Point: 
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y

  def __str__(self):
    return_string = "Instance of Point\n\n"
    return_string += f"x: {self.x}\ny: {self.y}"
    return return_string

  def __add__(self, other):
    print("Instance of Point\n")
    return(f"x: {self.x + other.x}\ny: {self.y + other.y}")
    return

  def __sub__(self,other):
    print("Instance of Point\n")
    return(f"x: {self.x - other.x}\ny: {self.y-other.y}")

  def __mul__(self, other):
    print("Instance of Point\n")
    return(f"x: {self.x * other.x}\ny: {self.y * other.y}")

  def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y:
      return True
    else:
      return False

  """ A simple representation of a point in 2d space"""
  pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
  point_one = Point(3,2)
  print(point_one)
  print()
  point_two = Point(5,3)
  print(point_two)
  print()
  point_three = point_one + point_two
  print(point_three)
  print()
  point_four = point_one - point_two
  print(point_four)
  print()
  point_five = point_one * point_two
  print(point_five)
  print()
  print(point_one == point_two) # prints False
```

Comment: Your `__mul__`, `__sub__`, and `__add__` functions are returning strings, not `Point`s.

Comment: how do i correct this?

Comment: I try to run your code, It works .What exactly is your issue ?

Comment: Have those three methods return new `Point` objects instead of strings.

Comment: No it will not return a Point object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a new `Point` object, you must create a new objects in your Operator overloaded methods such as `__add__ , __sub__ , __mul__`

Eg :

```
 def __add__(self, other):
    print("Instance of Point\n")
    newPoint = Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
    return newPoint
```